# Compare values in two hashamps and increment counter

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have two hashmaps A & B of type . I want to compare the values of the two maps simultaneously, keeping B's values as the reference for comparison, and increment correctValue counter if it finds the values are equal else increment incorrectValue counter.

For example,

```
    int correctValuesCounter = 0;
    int incorrectValuesCounter = 0;

    Map<Int, Double> A = new HashMap<Int, Double>();
    Map<Int, Double> B = new HashMap<Int, Double>();

    A.put(1, 0.0);
    A.put(2, 1.0);
    A.put(3, 0.0);
    A.put(4, 0.0);
    A.put(5, 1.0);
    A.put(6, 1.0);


    B.put(1, 0.0);
    B.put(2, 1.0);
    B.put(3, 0.0);
    B.put(4, 0.0);
    B.put(5, 1.0);
    B.put(6, 1.0);
```

Now, these map values are equal and hence, correctValuesCounter should be 6 and incorrectValuesCounter should be 0. Similarly, if A.put(3, 0.0) is changed to A.put(3, 1.0) and B(2, 1.0) is changed to B(2, 0.0) then correctValuesCounter will become 4 and incorrectValuesCounter will become 2 and so on.

What I have until now is not giving me the intended result so can someone please guide me in the right direction?

```
public void checkEqualValues(Map<Integer, Double> A, Map<Integer, Double> B)
    {       
        for(double value : A.values())
        {
            if(A.size() == B.size())
            {
                if(B.values().contains(value))
                {
                    correctValuesCounter++;
                }
                else
                    incorrectValuesCounter++;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Unequal list");
        }

        System.out.println("correctValuesCounter: "+correctValuesCounter);
        System.out.println("incorrectValuesCounter:"+incorrectValuesCounter);
    }
```

However, this returns true (i.e. `correctValuesCounter: 6`) for all permutations and combinations (even when I change values in either of the lists to unequal each other). Can someone please help?

Comment: Your logic to update the counters is incorrect. It does not check the key value pair, it just checks the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing your values with `contains`.

This essentially means you are incrementing your counter when ever a value in `B` is **contained** in `A`, not if it pertains to the same key!

Use a keyset-based iteration to compare values, as such:

```
if (A.size() != B.size()) {
    System.out.println("Different sizes :(");
}
for (Integer key: B.keySet()) {
    if (A.get(key) != null && A.get(key).equals(B.get(key))) {
        correctValuesCounter++;
    }
}
System.out.printf("Correct values counter: %d%n", correctValuesCounter);
```

**Output**

```
Correct values counter: 6
```

Answer (score 2):

You're checking if `B Map` **contains** the `A.value()`

You must get `a.getKey()` and compare it with the value from `b.get(a.getKey());`

Something like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<Int, Double> aEntry : A.entrySet())
    Int key = aEntry.getKey();
    double aVal = aEntry.getValue();
    double bVal = B.get(key);

    if (aVal == bVal) {
        correctValuesCounter++;
    } else {
        incorrectValuesCounter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not really checking if the B map contains the values in the right place, you're just checking whether it contains them **at all**. So you want to do something like get an iterator of the keys from A, walk through it and make sure that the same key in B contains the same value.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic to compare the HashMaps is incorrect. What you are essentially checking is that in all the values present in B, is a specific value present? This does not consider the key associated with the value. If I understand correctly, the code which you actually need is as follows:

```
public void checkEqualValues(HashMap<Integer, Double> A, HashMap<Integer, Double> B) {
    if (A.size() == B.size()) {
        for (int key : A.keySet()) {
            if (B.containsKey(key)) {
                if (Objects.equals(A.get(key), B.get(key))) {
                    correctValuesCounter++;
                }
            } else {
                incorrectValuesCounter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("correctValuesCounter: " + correctValuesCounter);
        System.out.println("incorrectValuesCounter:" + incorrectValuesCounter);
    } else {
       System.out.println("HashMaps are of different sizes");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a map to key your values.  You need to check that `A.get(value) == B.get(value)`.  Not that one value is contained in the other.

Furthermore, I think you want to check not only that `A.size() == B.size()'  but that the values all the same before proceeding?  Or else you will get an error trying to compare null to an integer.

```
 public void checkEqualValues(HashMap<Integer, Double> A, HashMap<Integer, Double> B) {
        int correctValuesCounter = 0, incorrectValuesCounter = 0;
        if (A.values().containsAll(B.values()) && B.values().containsAll(A.values()) ) {
            for (int key : A.keySet()) {
                if (A.get(key).equals(B.get(key))) {
                    correctValuesCounter++;
                } else {
                    incorrectValuesCounter++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("correctValuesCounter: " + correctValuesCounter);
            System.out.println("incorrectValuesCounter:" + incorrectValuesCounter);
        } else {
            if(A.size()!=B.size())
                System.out.println("HashMaps are of different sizes");
            System.out.println("HashMap's keys are different.");
        }
    }
```

Edit: Assuming that `A.get(key)` can't be null;